Telegram завершает сессии на всех устройствах после авторизации через Telethon
Я написал парсер для каналов Telegram, использую библиотеку Telethon. При тестирование на локальной машине, все работает корректно, при размещение на сервере, после авторизации(никакие запросы к API ещё не отправляются, специально оставил только авторизацию, чтобы проверить) telegram создает файлы сессий, а потом выходит из этого аккаунта со всех устройств, в чем может быть проблема.

Достаточно частый вопрос. Возможно этот ответ поможет
